# Table generator Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, input, dynamic, html-table

I'm trying to make a dynamic table generator with html/CSS/jQuery; I don't have much so far but can you have a look and help me out?

HTML

```
<span id="cols">Columns:</span>

<select id="coluna">
    <option disabled selected>Select</option>
    <option>0</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
</select>
<span class="ros">Rows:</span>

<select id="fila">
    <option disabled selected>Select</option>
    <option>0</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
</select>
<button class="criar">Generate</button>
<div id="tabelas"></div>
```

CSS

```
body{
  background:oldlace;
  font-family: "Eurostile LT Std";
}

select{
  margin-right:40px;
}
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var col = $('#coluna').val();
  var row = $('#fila').val();
  var tabela = ("<table>" + "</table>");
  var colunatabela = ("<tr></tr>");
  var titulotabela = ("<th></th>");
  var ceclulatabela = ("<td></td>");


  $('.criar').click(function(){  

    $(tabela).appendTo('#tabelas').then(function(){
      $(colunatabela).appendTo(tabela);
    });



  });

});
```

The idea is that the person inputs how many columns and rows he wants and the jQuery will add to the *tabelas* div a table and then the said columns and rows from values of the options selectors... Help please?

Here is a [PEN](http://codepen.io/angus/pen/zmLcd/) with the project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you can create a table generator.

### Demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52rr56pq/4/)

#### HTML:

Replace

```
<div id="tabelas"></div>
```

with

```
<table id="tabelas"></table>
```

---

#### CSS:

```
td, th, table {
    border:  solid 1px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

---

#### JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    String.prototype.repeat = function(n) {
        return new Array(n + 1).join(this); 
    }

    $('.criar').click(function () {
        $('table').empty();
        var col = parseInt($('#coluna').val());
        var row = parseInt($('#fila').val());
        var head = "<th>Heading</th>".repeat(row);
        var tableHead = "<tr>" + head + "</tr>"
        var tableData = "<td>Cookies</td>".repeat(row);
        var tableRow = "<tr>" + tableData + "</tr>";
        var table = tableRow;

        $('#tabelas').append(tableHead);

        for (i = 0; i < col; i++) {
            $('#tabelas tr:last').after(table);
        }
    });
});
```